# Show that max number of faces is $n^2/2 + n/2 + 1$ for an arrangement with $n(n-1)/2$ vertices and n^2 edges

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

I cannot understand how to show that $$faces \leq n^2/2 + n/2 + 1$$ for an arrangement with $n(n-1)/2$ vertices  and $n^2$ edges.
By using Euler's formula I showed that 
$$faces = n^2 + n/2 + 2$$

I have no idea how to improve upon that. Does it mean that Euler's formula is not tight?

Comment: Please include your steps to get your (second) equation for number of faces. [That would improve the question, and show you did some work.]

Comment: @coffeemath I did not do it simply because it is trivial

Comment: Yohan-- Your version started with $n^2$ instead of the expected $n^2/2,$ so I asked for step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler's formula for the polyhedron with $E$ edges, $V$ vertices and $F$ faces is:
$$E=V+F-2 \Rightarrow F=E-V+2.$$
Plugging the given expressions:
$$F=E-V+2=n^2-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+2=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}+2.$$
If any face of the polyhedron is removed, the equality changes to inequality:
$$F<E-V+2.$$
For example, for the tetrahedron:
$$F=E-V+2=6-4+2=4,$$
if one face is removed, then:
$$F=3<6-4+2=4.$$

Comment: It is not fully clear to me. I got equality using Euler's formula in the same way. But I do not understand your argument about inequality. You say we have +1 instead of +2 because we have strictly smaller < inequality instead of $\leq$?

Comment: Euler's formula works for polyhedron. You did not specify what figure you are considering (polyhedron or multifaceted figure). So if a polyhedron is disclosed (e.g. one vertex is detached), Euler's equality formula turns to inequality.

Comment: I cannot find references to this online.. even if it it disclosed, how does it affect faces? If region is unbounded then it is not considered to be a face?

Comment: Please, see my edit.

Comment: More on this site: https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/eulers-formula.html&hl=en-UZ